# Django filtering time

Tags: django

I have a model called Message and this has a field called in_response_to . I use this field to identify which messages are related to each other by storing the primary key of the original message inside each related message and I list all the messages via time created.

So for example I created 4 message and each of time are related to each other and shows the created time

```
Hello   1.00am 
My name is richard 2.00am 
What yours? 3.00am 
Kangarro 4.00am
```

and I retrieve object with the message  **What yours? 3.00am** . How can I show all the messages that are related to this object eariler than the created time?

```
class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recipient')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    in_response_to = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.body
```

views

```
messages = Message.objects.get(pk=id,recipient=request.user.id)
message = Message.objects.filter(in_response_to=messages.in_response_to )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you inverted `messages` with `message`. Assuming `message` is your single object, we'll filter messages like so:

```
messages = Message.objects.filter(in_response_to=message.in_response_to).filter(created__lt=message.created)
```

Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#lte) for more comparison examples (`lte` means `less than or equal` but you could use `lt`, `gt`, `gte` and so on)

About the `DateTime` thing:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

is one of the options you have (you have to `import datetime`). The other one is overriding your model's save method:

```
class Message(models.Model):

    # other fields omitted to keep it clean
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)        

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.created:
            self.created = datetime.datetime.now()
        return super(Message, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: well, `auto_now_add` is deprecated and, afaik, not a best practice. For a default datetime, you should override your `save()` method and set it there or change its default value with `default=datetime.datetime.now`